# Can you add conditions to the on clause of a relationship join in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Say I have the following two SQLAlchemy ORM classes:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimAddress'

    AddressKey = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... columns ...

class DealerOrganisation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimDealerOrganisation'

    DealerOrganisationKey = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... columns ...
    DealerOrganizationAddressKey = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('DimAddress.AddressKey'), nullable=False)
    # ... columns ...

    address = relationship('Address')
```

I can get dealer organizations and their address, if present, as follows:

```
session = Session()
query = session.query(DealerOrganisation).outerjoin(DealerOrganisation.address).options(contains_eager(DealerOrganisation.address))
```

This gives me SQL approximately like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM DimDealerOrganisation
LEFT JOIN DimAddress ON AddressKey = DealerOrganizationAddressKey
```

But what if I want to do an ORM query for only a subset of related objects:

```
SELECT *
FROM DimDealerOrganisation
LEFT JOIN DimAddress ON AddressKey = DealerOrganizationAddressKey AND ZipCode = '90210'
```

That is, I want all the dealers, but I only want their address if the zip code is 90210. As far as I can tell, join() and outerjoin() let you specify either a relationship or an explicit condition, but not both. In this contrived example I could use an explicit condition and get back rows instead of ORM objects, but it would be unwieldy in a real query involving multiple tables and one-to-many relations. I want to add additional conditions to the on clause but still have it populate the `address` attribute of the returned DealerOrganisation objects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [and_ operator from SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) in the join. I think it will look something like:

```
session = Session()
session.query(Table1).join(Table2, and_(Table1.address==Table2.address, Table1.zip == '90210'), isouter=True)
```

Comment: In my effort to make my question concise, I accidentally used an example that doesn't represent my exact scenario, but this helped me find the answer anyway. In my actual scenario, I have multiple relationships to the same table. I wondered, if I use explicit join conditions as in this answer, how will SQLAlchemy know which relationship goes with which join? As it turns out, you just have to use aliases and pass the same alias to both outerjoin() and the alias keyword argument of contains_eager() and SQLAlchemy will figure it out.